# Classroom API Invitations.list does not return userId field

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

A short description of the issue: userId field is not present in the invitations.list and invitations.get response.

What steps will reproduce the problem?

Create a course in google classroom
Authenticate in google OAuth2.0 playground
Send a request to list all sent invitations.
What is the expected output? What do you see instead? If you see error messages, please provide them. I expected to get the userId as a part of the response. After authentication and sending the request to the "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/invitations?courseId=*my course id*" I get the following response:

```
{
  "nextPageToken": "*next page token*", 
  "invitations": [
    {
      "courseId": "*course id*", 
      "role": "STUDENT", 
      "id": "*invitation id*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the documentation states that there should also be a "userId" field, which I am not seeing here.

The same thing happens when I use the "Try this API" section in the documentation. The response code is 200 but there is no userId.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*It appears that the only the users that have not accepted an invitation have their user IDs appear.*

#### This *could* be a bug...

The documentation for the [`invitations` resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations#Invitation) doesn't make it clear as to whether this is intended behaviour or not. I used the Try this API feature of the [`invitations.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list) method and I was able to retrieve the userId for *some* users, not not others. I followed up my search and it appears you have already filed this issue with Google on Issue Tracker:

- [Invitations.list does not return userId field](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155942624)

#### Things to do:

To make sure that you're always receiving the userId when it is available, you can specify in the request to retrieve all response fields with a wildcard (`*`). You can test this on the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list) feature by entering the courseId, expanding `Show standard parameters` and entering a `*` in the `fields` box.

**Note:** As this appears to be a bug, using the wildcard is *not* a solution; but something that may be helpful for users if attempting to retrieve a response key that isn't default.

- [REST Resource: `invitations` | Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations#Invitation)
- [Method `invitations.list` | Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list)
- [Invitations.list does not return userId field | Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155942624)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really apreciate it. Unfortunately putting an asterisk in the 'fields' field didn't help me to get the userId so I am pretty much convinced that it is a bug. Thanks again!

Comment: The `*` in the fields isn't a solution unfortunately, sorry I didn't make that clear. This looks like a bug with the method, or perhaps the documentation.

Comment: Still a bug in 2023 and the google issue tracker link is dead. Damn

Comment: @Gaspa79 welcome to google 